# Где достать тулчейн под BSD?

Tags: linux, freebsd

Где взять тулчейны под FreeBSD/macOS (а че, оба Unix, но не Linux). Хост - Linux. Есть ли под FreeBSD/macOS хотя бы аналог MinGW из Windows?

---

UPD: binutils у меня отказывается собираться, clang тоже несёт пургу:

```
 ~ $ clang -target=aarch64-pc-freebsd print.c
In file included from print.c:1:
/usr/include/stdio.h:27:10: fatal error: 'bits/libc-header-start.h' file not found
#include <bits/libc-header-start.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Хотя при указании в качестве цели любого Linux - собирает без проблем. `-static` с Linux-ом прокатывает, с BSD отказывается

Answer (score 1):

Чтоб сделать mingw для BSD - создай папку с базовыми файлами FreeBSD (качни из репозитория `base.txz` и пакеты с инклудами зависимостей) распакуй в этой папке собери gcc c нужной `--target` и укажи чтоб брал бсдшные инклуды.

Для clang аналогично нужна папка с инклудами, только компилятор можно не перекомпилировать.

https://smallhacks.wordpress.com/2018/01/08/c-cross-compilation-on-linux-for-the-freebsd-target-using-gcc-or-clang/

`bits/libc-header-start.h` не видит потому что в линуксе он в папке `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits` а у Вас архитектура `aarch64-pc-freebsd` качните инклуды с freebsd и укажите компилятору где их брать.

Comment: ну я просто из исходников собрал binutils-ы. До gcc пока руки не дошли